# writing int value to a binary file by fwrite

Tags: c, linux, binaryfiles, fwrite

I have the below example C code to write `int` and `char array` to a file on Linux OS.

```
int main(void){
    struct eg{
        int x;
        char y[3];
    };

    struct eg example_array[5] = {{ 0, {0}}};

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        example_array[i].x = i;
        strcpy(example_array[i].y,"12");
    }

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/home/ubuntu/example", "wb");
    fwrite(&example_array, sizeof(struct eg), 5, fp);
    fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

`nano example` shows the content as `^@^@^@^@12^@^@^A^@^@^@12^@^@^B^@^@^@12^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@`

`hexedit example` shows it as

```
00000000   00 00 00 00  31 32 00 00  01 00 00 00  31 32 00 00  02 00 00 00  31 32 00 00  00 00 00 00  ....12......12......12......
0000001C   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00                                                      ............
```

I don't see the `example_array[i].x` values on the binary file. Could anyone tell me how I should have used the `fwrite` on the above code?

and what do `^@^@^@^@^@` and `......` represent? are they blank spaces?

Comment: What architecture are you on? You know that x86 is little endian, right?

Comment: Yes I am on x86 but I will compile the code on armv4l architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^X` encodes bytes with non-printable ASCII values. `^@` means `0`, `^A` means `1`, `^B` means `2`, and so on.

```
   int   ch[] padding
-------- ---- -------
^@^@^@^@ 12^@   ^@
^A^@^@^@ 12^@   ^@
^B^@^@^@ 12^@   ^@
^@^@^@^@ ^@^@   ^@
^@^@^@^@ ^@^@   ^@
^@^@
```

Your computer stores the data starting with least significant byte. First four columns represent your `int`; the next three are the `char[3]`. Finally, there is a padding of 1 byte between the `struct`s.

Answer (score 1):

Each `^@` represents one binary 0x00, such as `^A` represents 0x01, `^B` represents 0x02 and so on. Take a look at the Hex dump you have posted. As sizeof( int ) is 4 on your platform, for each `example_array[i].x` you will find four bytes, followed by three more bytes that contain the string `y`. You will see, your first `x` is written as `00 00 00 00`, your second `x` is `01 00 00 00` and that's exactly how integers are stored on your system. If you wanted to write the values as strings, e.g. to have a platform independent output file, you can use something like

```
fprintf( fp, "%d %s ", example_array[i].x, example_array[i].y )
```